# Cast unresolved template overloaded class member

Tags: c++

I have a class with two overloaded members. One takes an integer, the other one is a template function taking one argument.

```
class MyClass
{
    public:
        void doSomething(int data){ std::cerr << data;}
        template <typename T> doSomething(T &&data){ std::cerr << data;}
};
```

I want to bind this function

```
MyClass myobject;
auto my_bind = std::bind(&MyClass::doSomething, &myobject, 2);
my_bind();
```

But this doesn't compile since the compiler cannot deduct which function to call.

> error: no matching function for call to 'bind(unresolved overloaded function type, MyClass*, int)'

I understand that I have to cast the function.

```
auto my_bind2 = std::bind(static_cast<void (MyClass::*)(int)>(&MyClass::doSomething), &myobject, 2);
```

And now it compiles and works as expected.

But what if I want to bind it with any other parameter to call the template function? Is this even possible? I cannot find the syntax.

This doesn't work:

```
auto my_bind3 = std::bind(static_cast<void (MyClass::*)(std::string)>(&MyClass::doSomething), &myobject, std::string("Hello"));
```

I would like to avoid using lambdas. I simplified the code for MCVE but in the actual code I am supposed to use member pointers.

Thank you for the help

Comment: *"I would like to avoid using lambdas."* - You prefer the hard way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should simply provide the address of a relevant instantiation of the *member function-template*:

```
auto my_bind3 = std::bind(&MyClass::doSomething<std::string&>, &myobject, std::string("Hello"));
                                 //Note the reference here ^^
```

The above works because `std::bind` copies its arguments, and since the `doSomething` member function template takes its argument by a *forwarding reference*, we need to take advantage of reference collapsing.

While something like the snippet below will "bind",

```
auto my_bind3 = std::bind(&MyClass::doSomething<std::string>, &myobject, std::string("Hello"));
                    //Note the absence of a reference here ^^
```

It is going to fail when you eventually call `my_bind3()`.

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7cb7da4dcd6a92cb)

---

If you can use a lambda, use it, because perfect forwading will kick in.

```
auto my_bind4 = [&myobject](){ myobject.doSomething(std::string("\nHullo")); };
```

Comment: Well that was easier than I thought... So even if the function takes a reference, the parameter is actually copied? I don't understand why the second one doesn't work though.

Comment: @dydil, [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) will always **store** a copy its arguments into the object it returns. When you invoke the `operator(...)` of the returned object, the already **stored** arguments are then passed unto the *bounded* function. Note that, `std::bind` doesn't change the semantics of the bounded function. (There is an exception to this when the "bounded" function is another `std::bind`)

Comment: The second fails because that instantiation will result to a function like `void doSomthing(std::string&& data)`. But when you invoke the "std::bind object", it will pass the stored argument by value, it doesn't convert it to `rvalue` say by calling `std::move(...)`. This fails because the instantiation expects an `rvalue`. ..~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ On the other hand, the first case works because it will create a function like `void doSomthing(std::string&&& data)`, and by reference collapsing rules, it turns to be `void doSomthing(std::string& data)`. Which will work nicely with `std::bind`

Comment: Thank you for the very clear explanation. I expected the deducted argument to be of type `std::string` and not rvalue reference, but it actually makes sense.